# How does this Python Hackerrank function work?

Tags: python

I am a complete beginner in terms of programming and I just started learning my first language, which is Python. Lately, I've been practising solving problems in Hackerrank and I got stuck at some "diagonal difference" problem.

The problem is completely new to me so I search the web for some answers and come across with this function that somebody made in github.

```
    def diagonalDifference(arr):
        prim =0
        sec=0
        length = len(arr[0])
        i=0                           #what does i=0 even do here?
        for count in range(length):
            prim += arr[count][count] #don't understand what "[count][count]" mean
            sec += arr[count][(length-count-1)] #don't understand this either
        return abs(prim-sec)
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it and see what happens and what are the variables values in each step?

Comment: See the kind of input the function takes.

Comment: `i` does nothing, you can remove it. `arr[x][y]` means that the element at the position `x, y` of `arr` (which I assume is a 2 dimensional square matrix).

Comment: The function seem to take a complex argument `arr`. Key to understand it is to have one or more example values for that argument.

Comment: Brackets are ususually used to index a container.  Example, if the container is a nested list `lst = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]`, then `lst[0][1]` returns `'b'` (since `[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]][0]` -> `['a", "b"][1]` -> `"b"`).  `arr` suggests you have an array.  Be aware that a numpy array can be [extended](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) beyond basic index.   Regarding `i`, it's not used anywhere else, so it does nothing.  Usually, it holds an initial count outside a loop.

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables in different places.  It helps to understand code.

Comment: Thanks for helping me guys, I now understand it

Answer (score 0):

First of all `i` here is unnecessary. Now, let's say we have a square matrix:

```
arr = 
[[1, 2, 4],
 [3, 5, 8],
 [6, 2, 1]]
The indices will be:
[[(0,0), (0,1), (0,2)],
 [(1,0), (1,1), (1,2)],
 [(2,0), (2,1), (2,2)]]
```

So the primary diagonal is `[(0,0),(1,1),(2,2)]`
And the secondary diagonal is: `[(0,2),(1,1),(2,0)]`

Now in the function:

```
length = len(arr[0])
arr[0] is := [1, 2, 4], i.e. the first row,
so length = 3
for count in range(length):
so count will have values: [0, 1, 2]
Now, for all the iterations:
    arr[count][count] will yield: arr[0][0], arr[1][1] and arr[2][2],
    hence giving the first diagonal.
And 
    arr[count][(length-count-1)] will yield: arr[0][(3-0-1)], arr[1][(3-1-1)],
    and arr[2][(3-2-1)], i.e arr[0][2], arr[1][1] and arr[2][0],
    which is the second diagonal
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is same code with further explanation. Basically this function sums the elements
of the upper left to bottom right diagonal storing the running total in prim, and sums
the elements of the upper right to bottom left diagonal storing the running total in sec. Then
the absolute value of the difference is returned. For an array the indexes are: arr[row][column]
from 0 to one less than the lenght of the array. Hope it helps

```
import numpy as np

def diagonalDifference(arr):
    prim = 0
    sec = 0
    length = len(arr[0])
    for i in range(length):
        print("Iteration:", i,
              "UL to BR Diagonal:", arr[i][i],
              "UR to BL Diagonal:", arr[i][(length-i-1)])
        # Get value of arr in the ith row and ith column (i.e. the UL to BR diagonal)
        # Add to the cummulative sum
        prim = prim + arr[i][i]

        # Get the value of arr in the ith row and the (length-i-1)th column
        # Columns traverse right to left (i.e. the UR to BL diagonal)
        sec = sec + arr[i][(length-i-1)]

    print("UL to BR Diagonal Sum:", prim,
          "----",
          "UR to BL Diagonal Sum:", sec)
    # Take the absolute value of the difference between the running totals
    return abs(prim-sec)

a = np.array([[1, 2, 4], [3, 4, 6], [3, 8, 1]])
print(a)
diagonalDifference(a)
```

Output:

```
[[1 2 4]
 [3 4 6]
 [3 8 1]]
Iteration: 0 UL to BR Diagonal: 1 UR to BL Diagonal: 4
Iteration: 1 UL to BR Diagonal: 4 UR to BL Diagonal: 4
Iteration: 2 UL to BR Diagonal: 1 UR to BL Diagonal: 3
UL to BR Diagonal Sum: 6 ---- UR to BL Diagonal Sum: 11
```